# Contentful media file name/extension validation

Tags: contentful

Contentful has a predefined file types validation (image, video, etc…) for media files, but I need to validate the file name (using regex) and/or extension. Is there a way to do that? Maybe using UI extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As replied from Contentful support, that would indeed not be possible right out of the box at the moment.

Also, UI extensions would be limited to entry management and not the actual assets themselves so it wouldn't help in this case.